# How to show $x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2=0 \subset \mathbb{CP}^2 \iff \mathbb{CP}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, singularity-theory, blowup, projective-varieties

I am currently trying to blow-up an $A_n$ singularity defined by the hypersurface equation:
\begin{equation}
z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^{n+1}=0 \subset \mathbb{C}^3
\end{equation}

Let $x_i, i=0,1,2$ denote the homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbb{CP}^2$, then going through the blow-up procedure one gets the hypersurface
\begin{equation}
x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2=0 \subset \mathbb{CP}^2 
\end{equation}
I know that this is equivalent to $\mathbb{CP}^1$, but I don't know how to show this explicitly.

Similarly, one also gets surfaces of the form for example
\begin{equation}
x_1^2+x_2^2=0 \subset \mathbb{CP}^2
\end{equation}
which should correspond to two $ \mathbb{CP}^1$ intersecting at a point, which again I don't know how to show explicitly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first equation
$$\tag{1}x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 0$$
defines a smooth quadratic curve $C$ in $\mathbb{CP}^2$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^1$. To see this, you can verify that the Veronese morphism
$$\mathbb{CP}^1 \to \mathbb{CP}^2, [s:t] \mapsto [s^2:st:t^2]$$
gives an isomorphism from $\mathbb{CP}^1$ to $C$.

For $$\tag{2}x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 0$$ note that you have a factorization $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = (x_1 + i x_2)(x_1 - i x_2)$. Each factor defines a line in $\mathbb{CP}^2$, both lines meet in the point $[0:0:1]\in \mathbb{CP}^2$

Comment: thanks very much for your answer. I can't see how $[s^2:st:t^2]$ lies on $C$. Sorry if that's obvious, I'm not too familiar in this area.

Comment: @red_trumpet That parametrization has image $x_0x_2 - x_1^2 = 0$, not the conic that OP is looking for.

Comment: In that case, would it be correct to define the coordinate change: $x_0:=s^2-t^2$,$x_1:=is^2+it^2$ and $x_2:=2st$ to then get $x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2=0$?